# Criar stored procedure com MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Eu faço EAD de banco e tenho muito pouco material para me ajudar a fazer minhas atividades. Eu estou com essa questão para resolver, se alguém puder me ajudar ou me ajudar com algum caminho de material de estudo eu fico muito agradecido.

Crie uma *stored procedure* chamada `sp_generate_quartos` que gera uma carga de 10 novos quartos de cada um dos 4 tipos de quartos existentes. Quanto aos números dos quartos, deve ser aleatórios de acordo com a seguinte regra:

```
Tipo de Quarto Número do Quarto
1              Entre 1000 e 1999
2              Entre 2000 e 2999
3              Entre 3000 e 3999
4              Entre 4000 e 4999
```

No *script*, no enquanto, deve ser feito da tal maneira que, se for
criado um quinto tipo de quarto, o *script* geraria 10 quartos para
ele também, entre os intervalos de 5000 e 5999, e assim por
diante.

TABELA TIPO QUARTO

```
CREATE TABLE tb_tipo_quarto
  (
    cd_tipo_quarto        TINYINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nm_tipo_quarto        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
    vl_tipo_quarto_diaria NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(cd_tipo_quarto)
  ) ;
```

Comment: O que você fez da consulta até agora?  Compartilha seu progresso para que possa ser ajudado...

Comment: Eu só consegui a estrutura do do Stored, as condições impostas no enunciado eu não sei fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Bom vamos lá, primeiro você terá que criar uma tabela de quartos para armazenar essas informações:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_quarto(
    cd_quarto INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cd_tipo_quarto INT NOT NULL,
    nm_quarto INT
);
```

Depois criamos a procedure onde passaremos o numero do quarto 1,2,3 etc... e ele irá inserir na tb_quartos 10 quartos randomicos entre os números que você passou(milhar de cada número), caso os quartos já possuam 10 quartos a procedure não faz nada, segue:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_gera_carga_quarto;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_gera_carga_quarto(
    p_cd_tipo_quarto INT
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_n_quarto INT;
    DECLARE v_qtd_quarto INT;
    DECLARE v_cont INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE v_quarto_existe TINYINT;
    DECLARE v_inicio INT;
    DECLARE v_fim INT;

    WHILE v_cont <= 10 DO

        SET v_inicio = p_cd_tipo_quarto * 1000;
        SET v_fim = v_inicio + 999;

        SELECT
                COUNT(*)
        INTO v_qtd_quarto
        FROM tb_quarto
        WHERE cd_tipo_quarto = p_cd_tipo_quarto;

        IF v_qtd_quarto = 10 THEN

            SET v_cont = 11;

        ELSE 

            SET v_n_quarto = (select floor(v_inicio+(rand()*(v_fim-v_inicio))));

            SELECT
                    IF(COUNT(*) > 0,1,0)
            INTO v_quarto_existe
            FROM tb_quarto
            WHERE nm_quarto = v_n_quarto;

            IF v_quarto_existe = 0 THEN
                INSERT INTO tb_quarto(cd_tipo_quarto,nm_quarto)
                VALUES(p_cd_tipo_quarto,v_n_quarto);
                SET v_cont = v_cont + 1;
            END IF;


        END IF;

    END WHILE;

    SELECT 'carga de quartos geradas';

END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Ex carga gerada do quarto 1 do número 1000 ao 1999;

```
CALL sp_gera_carga_quarto(1);
```

Retornando os quartos:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM tb_quarto
WHERE cd_tipo_quarto = 1;
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]